# How do I bring up the "Advanced Find" Dialog in Outlook with VBA

Tags: vba, outlook-2003

I know how to do a search using the `Outlook.AdvancedSearch()` method. What I want is based on the parameters for my search to populate the build in advanced find dialog with VBA code,  as seen below.

What I want is in the end of the search for the end user to select and move from the results selectively.

[image: Advanced Find Dialog]

**Edit**
If this is not possible (as my searches indicate) then how can I save the results into a search folder? When I use the `Search.Save()` method and the folder already exists, then I get an error. At least I would like the make the search folder active when the search is complete.

[image: Error Message]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can **parse a folder** within the namespace `ns` with this kind of code:

```
ns.Folders("Personal Folders").Folders("Inbox")
```

Found in this thread: [Access Outlook default folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6105064/outlook-vba-default-folder)

Thus, you can check if your search folder already exists before creating it.

You can also **prevent the error** or handle it, for instance:

```
On Error Resume Next
'Create folder (won't raise error if already exists)
On Error GoTo 0
```

Eventually, to **activate the search folder**, you can use the `CurrentFolder` property:

```
Sub ChangeCurrentFolder()
    Dim myolApp As Outlook.Application
    Dim myNamespace As Outlook.NameSpace
    Set myolApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set myNamespace = myolApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set myolApp.ActiveExplorer.CurrentFolder = _
    myNamespace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderCalendar)
End Sub
```

See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa211818(v=office.11).aspx) for more information.