# VBA - Outlook 2010 - Search variable in URLs and move messages to the corresponding folders

Tags: vba, outlook

In Outlook 2010 I have thousand email products updates for multiple customers with URL in 
message body like that:

http://shop.khlynov.net/products/en/PRODUCT_ID_VARIABLE/enter.asp?z=UNIQUE_ACCESS_KEY

something like that:

http://shop.khlynov.net/products/en/VOP08011316314153US/enter.asp?z=AFE38DC1F69084D0B95648B21B8F1DC65E2D7E9A11A710590C60AA49390E2DC928

where:

- all before `VOP08011316314153US` - constant part of URL
- `VOP08011316314153US/` - product ID variable (there are thousands)
- `enter.asp?z=AFE38DC1F69084D0B95648B21B8F1DC65E2D7E9A11A710590C60AA49390E2DC928` - access key unique for each customer (I don't use it)

I want that a script:

1. search for `PRODUCT_ID_VARIABLE` in all messages in Outlook Inbox folder
2. create subfolders named according to the `PRODUCT_ID_VARIABLE` (if it doesn't exist)
3. move messages with different PRODUCT_ID_VARIABLE into corresponding subfolders.

In the example below a script should create folders `VOP08011316314153US` and `VOP08011316314154US` (if they don't already exist) and move there all messages with product IDs `VOP08011316314153US` and `VOP08011316314154US` in URLs:

Here's an example of how the email body may look like:

```
<table align="left">
    <tr>
        <td style="padding: 9px;" align="left">
            <p style="font-size: 10px; font-family: 'Trebuchet MS', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
                            color: #333333;">
               <span style="color: #9B0124;">PRODUCT LINK: </span><br />
                  <a href="http://shop.khlynov.net/products/en/VOP23011304005259US/enter.asp?z=ABCC226C7CBA08F2D0CE2BAB7CBFE493E04D9533489C3FF245EB4061D0FA6A7D18" target="_blank" style="text-decoration: none; color: #333333;">http:/<wbr>/<wbr>shop.khlynov.net/<wbr>products/<wbr>en/<wbr>VOP23011304005259US/<wbr>enter.asp?z=ABCC226C7CBA08F2D0CE2BAB7CBFE493E04D9533489C3FF245EB4061D0FA6A7D18</a>
           </p>
       </td>
   </tr>
</table>


INBOX
-VOP08011316314153US
-- Email 1
-- Email 2
-- Email ...
-- Email X
-VOP08011316314154US
-- Email 1
-- Email 2
-- Email ...
-- Email X
```

I am very new in VBA coding. Could anyone help to write a code from a scratch?

---

I've just found that your macro work well with plain text but doesn't work with HTML letters. Here's the part of HTML code:

```
<table align="left">
                <tr>
                    <td style="padding: 9px;" align="left">
                        <p style="font-size: 10px; font-family: 'Trebuchet MS', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
                            color: #333333;">
                            <span style="color: #9B0124;">PRODUCT LINK: </span>
                            <br />
                            <a href="http://shop.khlynov.net/products/en/VOP23011304005259US/enter.asp?z=ABCC226C7CBA08F2D0CE2BAB7CBFE493E04D9533489C3FF245EB4061D0FA6A7D18" target="_blank" style="text-decoration: none; color: #333333;">http:/<wbr>/<wbr>shop.khlynov.net/<wbr>products/<wbr>en/<wbr>VOP23011304005259US/<wbr>enter.asp?z=ABCC226C7CBA08F2D0CE2BAB7CBFE493E04D9533489C3FF245EB4061D0FA6A7D18</a>
                        </p>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
```

Comment: Hi Sergey, welcome to Stackoverflow. I think there are two approach to this problem. 1. is your approach, do everything in VBA.  [search in Inbox](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6105064/outlook-vba-default-folder),  [create folder and move mailItem](http://superuser.com/questions/489124/create-new-folder-for-new-sender-name-and-move-message-into-new-folder) , [REGEX](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3865500/regular-expression-rules-in-outlook-2007) 2. Create a Rule in Outlook on Incoming email --> look for specific word in body of mail--> run a script --> those in Method 1

Comment: Thanks, VMAtm! I am very new in VBA. Could you please help me with a code?

Comment: It's urgent need! I would even donate some money into your PayPal account if you help me to write the code!

Comment: and the mailBody ONLY contains the URL?

Comment: Message bodies contain HTML with some text, URLs with different patterns, and 2 identical product update URLs with the pattern I quoted above: one as graphic button and another as text. I also noticed that the patterns of product IDs always have VOP in the beginning and US at the end divided with 14 numbers only such as: VOP??????????????US

Comment: I found simple macro that finds predefined sender name and moves moves all the item into predefined folder:

Comment: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1RAKRXfW07kHq0f0j3P9PaU6-fgQXwVUTlklDVaHIDbw/edit

Comment: Would you please help me to modify it so that it search for variable in message bodies and create new folders corresponding to the variable?

Comment: see my answer below and try it out

Answer (score 1):

The macro will run for ALL mail in INBOX .. it may takes some time

```
' run this macro
Sub main_procedure()
    On Error GoTo eh:
    Dim ns As Outlook.NameSpace
    Dim folder As MAPIFolder
    Dim item As Object
    Dim msg As MailItem

    Set ns = Session.Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set folder = ns.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
    MsgBox "Total Number of mail in your inbox " & folder.Items.Count
    For Each item In folder.Items

        If (item.Class = olMail) Then
            Set msg = item
            If InStr(msg.Body, "http://shop.khlynov.net/products/en/") > 0 Then
                URL = msg.Body
                createAndMoveMail URL, msg

            ElseIf InStr(msg.Subject, "http://shop.khlynov.net/products/en/") > 0 Then
                URL = msg.Subject
                createAndMoveMail URL, msg
            End If
        End If
    Next


    Exit Sub
eh:
    MsgBox Err.Description, vbCritical, Err.Number
End Sub



Sub createAndMoveMail(ByVal URL As String, ByRef mail As MailItem)
Dim productID As String
Dim URLPath As String
Dim folderExist As Boolean
Dim startIndex As Long
Dim found As Boolean
On Error goto 0
found = False

Do While Not found
    productID = ""
    startIndex = InStr(URL, "http://shop.khlynov.net/products/en/")
    If startIndex = 0 Then
        Exit Sub
    End If
    URLPath = Mid(URL, startIndex)
    URLPath = Mid(URLPath, Len("http://shop.khlynov.net/products/en/") + 1)
    'update new url
    URL = URLPath
    If InStr(ULRPath, "/") = 0 Then
        Exit Sub
    End If
    productID = Mid(URLPath, 1, InStr(URLPath, "/") - 1)
    If Len(productID) = 19 And InStr(productID, "VOP") > 0 And InStr(productID, "US") > 0 Then
        found = True
        Exit Do
    End If
Loop



If Not found Then
    Exit Sub
End If





Dim myInbox As Outlook.MAPIFolder
Set myInbox = Outlook.GetNamespace("MAPI").GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)

folderExist = False
For i = 1 To myInbox.Folders.Count
    If myInbox.Folders.item(i).Name = productID Then
        folderExist = True
        Set myDestinationFolder = myInbox.Folders.item(i)
        Exit For
    End If
Next
If Not folderExist Then
    Set myDestinationFolder = myInbox.Folders.Add(productID, olFolderInbox)
End If

mail.Move myDestinationFolder
End Sub
```

Reference:  [read inbox mail item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6105064/outlook-vba-default-folder) [create mail folder,move mail item](https://superuser.com/questions/489124/create-new-folder-for-new-sender-name-and-move-message-into-new-folder)

Comment: have a try on this macro, **IMPORTANT** make sure your security setting is `ENABLE ALL MACRO`.   If there's any error, let me know WHICH LINE it highlights and what's the error msg

Comment: Thanks Larry! Where should I place your code? To ThisOutlookSession or to Module 1? Should I see only one macro main_procedure when running macro by pressing Alt+F8 in Outlook?

Comment: Yes, both locations are fine.  Yes, only main_procedure should be seen. Run that  macro

Comment: Would it work with IMAP Inbox folder? How should I change it in order to work?

Comment: As long as you are using outlook, I think the code will work and if my code works for you, you can mark it as accepted.

Comment: Just checked. It doesn't work in IMAP folders. Should I change somehting in order to make it work in IMAP?

Comment: my code is hardcoding olFolderInbox , you may want to take a look (http://www.outlookcode.com/codedetail.aspx?id=628)[loop through outlook folders]  Btw, I am away from computer for the next 20hours.

Comment: Hi, Larry! Not sure if you have read my answer. There are two problems: 1. Macro doesn't work with HTML in message bodies I quoted above. 2. For some reason the macro moves some plain messages and some  not so I have to run it again for each message. Would you help me please to fix the code?

Comment: The problem maybe that the messages have several hyperlinks with different patterns and only last two refer to Product ID

Comment: Hi, ok wait, so you mean the mail message may have some message with "http://shop.khlynov.net/products/en/" but without product id in the front part of the message? Wait

Comment: Thanks Larry! I've just checked new code. It doesn't fix the problem. For all plain text messages with only one Product ID link it works fine. But for HTML messages with several different types of hyperlinks (Terms, FAQ, Login, etc.) it moves messages to folder "HYPERLINK: "http"

Comment: HTML body contains at the beginning links like that:  http://www.khlynov.net/fileadmin/mail_templates/ and other subdirs

Comment: Should I post entire HTML body for your convenience?

Comment: Thanks, Larry! It now works with HTML! The second problem remains:  it stops after moving first two letters. To move others I should rerun macro. What's wrong?

Comment: @SergeyRusskikh I created 5 consecutive sample mail in your format and the macro would create/move them to the destination folder at once... how many emails are in your outlook inbox? How are the target email distributed in the list inside the outlook inbox? how long does it take to run the macro? Any error message?

Comment: Hi, try the new code, this should fix a bug to error the script

Comment: Hi Larry! Sorry, it no longer works even doesn't create folders. I have thousands of emails. First I have to move them manually to Outlook.pst Inbox as macro doesn't work inside IMAP. Previous version of your macro only moved two first messages into appropriate folders inside Inbox and all the rest messages remained inside Inbox  root. The macro run about 1-2 seconds. Are there any issue?

Comment: can you copy the code and try again? Hopefully there should be Some error message. and IT SHOULD NOT run for only 1-2 seconds for 1000+ email. I added a line to show the No. of mail in your inbox, see if the number is correct

Comment: The new code only shows a message saying: "Total number of email in your Inbox 4056" but doesn't create folders or move messages

Comment: I tried to debug and it went fine through 2 passes but it stopped at mail.Move myDestinationFolder for the third pass

Comment: That's strange, 2 things we can do. 1 if it's ok, capture our outlook's structure to imgur and have the link here.  2. Copy my code and raise other question so the experts can help you out.

Comment: @SergeyRusskikh It stops at that lane, and if you step over, No error message?  Please yourself to my latest version.  And the current version is WORKING properly for the first 2 mail or NOT?

Comment: Do not loop through all messages in a folder. Use Items.Find/FindNext or Items.Restrict.

Comment: @DmitryStreblechenko Thanks for the suggestion. Can you briefly explain to me the reason behind `why not to loop through all message` ? Is it a performance issue? What do you suggest me to use if I need to loop through all MESSAGE-IDs of mails in a folder?

Comment: 0down vote
 


Yes, it is a performance issue. You are not processing all items in the folder, only those that have a particular string in the message body.