# How do I select which account I want to create an outlook item for?

Tags: vba, outlook, outlook-2016

I'm writing a script that creates and updates an outlook note. Everything works fine except for one issue.

It creates and updates the note on my personal mailbox and I need it to create and maintain the note on a department mailbox that we all have access to(I have two accounts set up in my Outlook).

It is behaving this way despite the script being triggered by a rule on the department mailbox and being given mail items for the department mailbox. How do I tell VBS/Outlook which notes folder/account I want to use? I cannot find anything anywhere that outlines how to select which account the note will be created under.

I am using Outlook 2016.

```
Set olkFolder = Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderNotes)
Set olkNote = olkFolder.Items.Find("[Subject] = 'Sequential Number'")
If TypeName(olkNote) = "Nothing" Then
    Set olkNote = Application.CreateItem(olNoteItem)
    olkNote.Body = "Sequential Number" & vbCrLf & "NextValue=" & STARTING_VALUE + 1
    GetNextNumber = STARTING_VALUE
Else
    arrLines = Split(olkNote.Body, vbCrLf)
    For Each varLine In arrLines
        If Left(varLine, 10) = "NextValue=" Then
            GetNextNumber = CInt(Mid(varLine, 11))
            olkNote.Body = "Sequential Number" & vbCrLf & "NextValue=" & GetNextNumber + 1
        End If
    Next
End If
```

Comment: can you provide your code ?

Comment: Added to initial post

Comment: Can you post complete code? And what windows are using?

Answer (score 0):

You can either [move](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff860683.aspx) the note you created or [add](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff861028.aspx) directly to the folder in the other account.

From the link, the code to Add:

```
Sub AddContact() 
    Dim myNamespace As Outlook.NameSpace 
    Dim myFolder As Outlook.Folder 
    Dim myItem As Outlook.ContactItem 
    Dim myOtherItem As Outlook.ContactItem 

    Set myNamespace = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI") 
    Set myFolder = myNamespace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderContacts) 
    Set myOtherItem = myFolder.Items("Dan Wilson") 
    Set myItem = myFolder.Items.Add 
    myItem.CompanyName = myOtherItem.CompanyName 
    myItem.BusinessAddress = myOtherItem.BusinessAddress 
    myItem.BusinessTelephoneNumber = myOtherItem.BusinessTelephoneNumber 
    myItem.Display 
End Sub
```

If you have the mailbox in your navigation pane, "navigate down the tree". https://stackoverflow.com/a/6116820/1571407

```
ns.Folders("Personal Folders").Folders("Inbox")
```

In your code:

```
Set olkFolder = ns.Folders("name of other mailbox").Folders("Notes")
```

Whether the folder is in your navigation pane or not you may use [CreateRecipient](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff869575(v=office.15).aspx) as described in the other answer.

Comment: What I can't find is *how* to add it directly to that folder.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `Application.CreateItem`, either open the folder from another mailbox using `Application.Session.CreateRecipient` / `Application.Session.GetSharedDefaultFolder` and call `MAPIFolder.Items.Add` or (if the mailbox is already available in Outlook) drill down to that folder starting from `Application.Session.Folders` and (again) call `MAPIFolder.Items.Add`.

Replace

```
Set olkFolder = Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderNotes)
...
Set olkNote = Application.CreateItem(olNoteItem)
```

with

```
set recip = Session.CreateRecipient("SomeOtherUser@YourDomain.demo")
Set olkFolder = Session.GetSharedDefaultFolder(recip, olFolderNotes)
...
Set olkNote = olkFolder.Items.Add
```

Comment: Could you maybe provide an example of how to use these? I'm not exactly a VBA or outlook expert so now I'm just more confused than before... It really should not be complicated to tell outlook "create a note in this mailbox's default notes folder".

Comment: It is really not complicated. See the updated answer.

Comment: Is the mailbox containing this folder setup as an additional mailbox/account in Outlook, or do you only have delegate access to it?

Comment: @Eric legault It is an actual mailbox/account in outlook. None of these solutions have worked for me despite running error free. I don't understand why it literally isn't as simple as `session.getdefaultfolder(account, olFolderNotes)`

Comment: "Error free"? Can you actually step though your code one line at a time and see which line errors out or returns an unexpected value?

Comment: So then in addition to Dmitry's code, you need to loop through the NameSpace.Accounts collection until you find the Account object for the other mailbox.  Then use Account.DeliveryStore to get a Store object, and use Store.GetDefaultFolder or Store.GetRootFolder to look for the Folder object you need.

Comment: Really? Honestly, at this point it isn't worth it. I'll just map a drive and keep the needed data on a share. I've spent days and days on this. I didn't think accessing the notes folder on a second email account would be so ridiculously difficult(it shouldn't be) and the documentation from MS is trash, at best. I'm so frustrated I'm tempted to switch the whole company to Lotus Notes(yes, I do know how bad Lotus is)... Thanks for the help guys, you did what you could.